# What does fingerprint data look like?

Tags: fingerprint, fingerprinting

Are there any datasets of digitized data from fingerprints (not-images)? Basically, we're planning an application that works on fingerprint data and wondering if the output by fingerprint readers are standardized and if so, are there some reference sets / data sheets we can look at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the United States **[FBI Biometrics](https://www.fbibiospecs.org/)** website.

I found the **[NIST ITL American National Standards for Biometrics](http://fingerprint.nist.gov/standard/index.html)**.  The Data Format for the Interchange of Fingerprint Facial, & Other Biometric Information – Part 1 is a 164 page pdf file.  It's NIST Special Publication 500-271.

The Data Format for the Interchange of Fingerprint Facial, & Other Biometric Information – Part 2 is a 464 page pdf file.  It's NIST Special Publication 500-275.

NIST is the (United States) National Institute of Standards and Technology.